# Wrong path in file_put_contents using Laravel Windows

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I have to develop on a project that already exists. But I am adding new features and I have to stage an environment to test. Thus, I chose the Cloudways platform. I upload my files using Filezilla but when I launch my website, I have the

> ErrorException
> file_put_contents(C:\wamp64\www\myapp\htdocs\storage\framework/sessions/l7OUJvDvv4UsvRPb7LNCIt8JNyVYRmE401P6zlKr):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

The error is at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:135`

I think it tries to create a new file with the path given. I know that the path that Cloudways is using is the one on my local environment. But I want it to access to the path on the server. I have read lots of forums but I don't find any answers...

My Laravel version is `7.30.6` and php version is `7.4.26`

I've tried to reinstall Laravel and Composer and do the route:cache and views:cache

Also, I read on forums that the `config/filesystems.php` as to be like this:

[image: that]

but it's already the case.

Comment: Check if you have those folders `storage/framework/sessions` in your project's root. If you find at least one missing, create it and the one(s) inside it. This should fix your issue or at least provide more clues on why this happened.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already have those folders. Maybe I can delete one and recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `php artisan config:clear` and then upload the project via Filezilla

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it solved nothing. I still have the same issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Inside the folder `/storage/framework/sessions/FileSessionHandler`, I had to modify the value of the `$path` variable.